# Not able to browse the Solr Admin UI page

Tags: solr

I have configured the Solr , in one of the Linux environment. Through command i can see the there is one solr node currently  active on that environment, But when am trying to access the Admin URL , from outside it is not able to open the link. 
The URL used is http://Ipaddress:8080/solr

Can anyone suggest  how to access the URL outside linux.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, I have manually  started the Solr on 8080 port, earlier by default it was starting on 8983 but in either cases issue same , I can't access the UI screen

Comment: Do you know how to browse UI screen locally in Linux environment

Comment: 1. Did your solr linux server block 8080 port? 2. check `solr_base\server\logs\` to see r there any error.

Comment: @EricWang i checked the solr.log, it is having the below error                          
WARN  - 2016-01-04 12:29:55.716; [   ] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext; Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@346421c8{/solr,null,null}{/solr.war}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Temp dir /opt/solr-5.2.1/server/solr-webapp not useable: writeable=false, dir=true at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.configureTempDirectory(WebInfConfiguration.java:384)   am not able understand could you please help

Comment: @AdarshHDDev Maybe your solr admin failed to start, `writeable=false` might means it don't have write permission on some folder, thus the war file can't be deployed, check your solr dir permission, or try start with `sudo`.

Comment: @EricWang : i did the changes and started the solr with Sudo , now there is no error but still am not able to browse the URL

Comment: According to the log, did solr started? If it started maybe check whether your linux has firewall?

Comment: @EricWang :  according to the log it started, and i got the firewall opened but still  am not able to access how to resolve or debug

Comment: What is the tip in the browser? Did u input the ip correctly? Try ping the ip to see is that correct.

Comment: The IP address is correct , there is no tip as such , the browser is just saying  webpage not available.

Comment: Either solr not started, check the logs, or you have a firewall, I don't have enough info to determine ...

Comment: @EricWang : i found the issue, issue is with the IPtables service on Linux environment , if that service is running then am not able to access the url. need to find out why... any suggestions

Comment: iptable is a kind of firewall, config it to allow access to from your machine to the solr port on server, check `iptables` command on google.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric got the issue fixed, i made an entry of the port in Iptables after that am able to browse the URL. thanks a lot for your Inputs